# Overlapping Concurrent Sessions PSQL for each hour

Tags: postgresql, overlapping

I am struggling to find an appropriate solution for this for a while. I have a table named *sessions*.

The table has 3 fields:

- session_id - represents a unique identification of the user's session
- timestamp - the time of when the user made an action
- action - either a login or logout

...

I track when the user logged in and when he logged out.

| session_id | action | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | login | 2021-11-09 10:03 |
| 2 | login | 2021-11-09 10:15 |
| 1 | logout | 2021-11-09 10:48 |
| 3 | login | 2021-11-09 11:03 |
| 4 | login | 2021-11-09 11:43 |
| 5 | login | 2021-11-09 14:14 |
| 5 | logout | 2021-11-09 15:03 |
| 3 | logout | 2021-11-09 15:08 |
| 4 | logout | 2021-11-09 16:03 |
| 2 | logout | 2021-11-09 17:01 |

Essentially, I would like to have an output table, that would show how many concurrent sessions were there on each hour:

| timestamp | concurrent_sessions |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-09 10:00 | 2 |
| 2021-11-09 11:00 | 3 |
| 2021-11-09 12:00 | 3 |
| 2021-11-09 13:00 | 3 |
| 2021-11-09 14:00 | 4 |
| 2021-11-09 15:00 | 4 |
| 2021-11-09 16:00 | 2 |
| 2021-11-09 17:00 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a table of timestamp ranges, then join with a table of timestamps, aggregate and count:

```
SELECT times.t, count(*)
FROM generate_series(
        TIMESTAMP '2021-11-09 10:00:00',
        TIMESTAMP '2021-11-09 17:00:00',
        INTERVAL '1 hour'
     ) AS times(t)
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT session_id,
                     tsrange(li.timestamp, lo.timestamp, '[]') AS range
              FROM mytable AS li
                 LEFT JOIN mytable AS lo USING (session_id)
              WHERE li.action = 'login'
                AND lo.action = 'logout'
             ) AS q
      ON q.range @> times.t
GROUP BY times.t;
ORDER BY times.t
```

Comment: This is correct. Please edit the answer and use the correct name `tsrange` instead of `tzrange` so that I can accept the answer as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for spotting and fixing my typo.